# how can get data textbox

Tags: asp.net, c

```
  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select usr_name,usr_surname,usr_passwd,usr_sorumluluk_kod from ZRR_Users where usr_id='" + Session["user_id"] + "'", conn);
            conn.Open();//conenction open
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", Session["usr_id"].ToString());
            dr.Read();

                txtname.Text = dr["usr_name"].ToString();
                txtsurname.Text = dr["usr_surname"].ToString();
                txtpasswd.Text = dr["usr_passwd"].ToString();
                txtSorKodu.Text = dr["usr_sorumluluk_kod"].ToString();



            conn.Close();//conenction close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the name of the column begin returned from the database where "ColumnName" is. If it is a string, you can use .ToString(). If it is another type, you need to convert it using System.Convert.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
     txtname.Text = dr["usr_name"].ToString();
     txtsurname.Text = dr["usr_surname"].ToString();
     txtpasswd.Text = dr["usr_passwd"].ToString();
     txtSorKodu.Text = dr["usr_sorumluluk_kod"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to provide the sql-parameter before you call `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`
2. The sql-parameter name mus be part of the sql query (`usr_id=@userID`)
3. You have to cast the session value to the correct datatype(e.g. `(int)Session["user_id"]`)

---

```
string sql = @"select usr_name,usr_surname,usr_passwd,usr_sorumluluk_kod 
               from ZRR_Users 
               where usr_id=@userID";
using(var conn=new SqlConnection("Your Connection-String"))
using (var cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open(); 
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", (int)Session["user_id"]); // cast to the correct datatype
    using (var dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            txtname.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("usr_name"));
            txtsurname.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("usr_surname"));
            txtpasswd.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("usr_passwd"));
            txtSorKodu.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("usr_sorumluluk_kod"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnk u your answer but its not correct my proble is getdata from sesion

Comment: It _is_ correct, even if it doesn't solve your first issue(you haven't mentioned that you don't get the session value), it'll solve your second and third issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ToString()))
            {

                string sqlString = "select usr_name,usr_surname,usr_passwd,usr_sorumluluk_kod from ZRR_Users where usr_id=@userID";

                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.Connection.Open();

                var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read()) 
                    {

                        txtname.Text = reader.GetString(0)
                        txtsurname.Text = reader.GetString(1);
                        txtpasswd.Text = reader.GetString(2);
                        txtSorKodu.Text = reader.GetString(3);
                     }
                }
        }
```

Comment: _"Try this"_ So what issue exactly did this answer solve and why? Apart from that, you are using a sql-parameter in the query which you never add. This will cause an exception.